# PHP: How to creat array version this function correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, function, preg-replace, case

`$data    = 'this is appLe and ApPle';` 
`$search  = 'apple';` // For example a want use `$search` how array with many words `$search = array("apple","pear")` 
`$replace = 'pear';` // `$replace = array("pen","pupil")`

## How convert this function to use array words in $search and $replace ?

```
$data = preg_replace_callback('/\b'.$search.'\b/i', function($matches) use ($replace)
{
   $i=0;
   return join('', array_map(function($char) use ($matches, &$i)
   {
      return ctype_lower($matches[0][$i++])?strtolower($char):strtoupper($char);
   }, str_split($replace)));
}, $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a key-value array and use the keys to build a dynamic pattern to match the keys as whole words in a case insensitive way (or even a simple `/\b\w+\b/` regex to match any word) and test if the key exists inside the array (with `!empty($arr[strtolower($matches[0])])`). If it exists, process, else, use the found match value.

```
$data    = 'this is appLe and ApPle and also a pEar here'; 
$search = array("apple","pear");
$replace = array("pen","pupil");
$arr = array_combine($search, $replace);
$pat = '/\b(?:' . implode("|", array_keys($arr)) . ')\b/i';
$data = preg_replace_callback($pat, function($matches) use ($arr)
{
   $i=0;
   return !empty($arr[strtolower($matches[0])]) ? join('', array_map(function($char) use ($matches, &$i)
   {
      return ctype_lower($matches[0][$i++])?strtolower($char):strtoupper($char);
   }, str_split($arr[strtolower($matches[0])]))) : $matches[0];
}, $data);
echo $data; // => this is pen and PeN and also a pUpiL here
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/djoLW2).

Comment: Works well but there is one problem .. When I enter **Pear** the script works a little incorrectly and in response gives **PupiL** and not **Pupil**. Why is this happening? And how can this be corrected? And how to make so that this script worked and in other codings for example for **Cyrillici**?

Comment: I think you asked to only add array support in *this* question. If you have another, please feel free to ask. However, here is a hint: to enable Unicode string processing here, add a `u` modifier to the regex (`'/\b(?:' . implode("|", array_keys($arr)) . ')\b/iu';`) and replace all `strto...` with `mb_strto...`. `ctype_lower` can also be replaced with `preg_match('~^\p{Ll}+\z~u', $m)`.

Comment: '$data    = 'Alex have many cats at home.'; 
$search = array("apple","pear","alex");
$replace = array("pen","pupil","александр");
$search = array_map("utf8_encode", $search);
$replace = array_map("utf8_encode", $replace);
$arr = array_combine($search, $replace);
$arr = array_map("utf8_encode", $arr);'

Comment: `$pat = '/\b(?:'.implode("|", array_keys($arr)) . ')\b/iu';
$hint = preg_replace_callback($pat, function($matches) use ($arr)
{
$i=0;
return !empty($arr[mb_strtolower($matches[0])]) ? join('',array_map(function($char) use ($matches, &$i){return ctype_lower($matches[0][$i++])?mb_strtolower($char):mb_strtoupper($char); }, str_split($arr[mb_strtolower($matches[0])]))) : $matches[0];}, $data);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8");`

Comment: `ctype_lower` does not deal with Unicode letters. Not sure you need it. Anyway, that is already another question.

Comment: I just did not understand you when you told me about `preg_match`. I could do whatever I could but I was not. If you can help me help please. I can write all the words from the beginning in the upper case to the array and then to the lower one and using str_replace or str_ireplace will replace all the words but this is not an effective method and takes a lot of time during the execution...